# Definite article usage

Tags: definite-articles

What's the difference between the two sentences and which one is grammatically correct:

"She is the best and wisest girl in the class.",

"She is the best and the wisest girl in the class."?

Comment: @Elasthiccgirl No. This is a different Q.

Comment: @Elasthiccgirl It's not about choosing definite vs. indefinite article. I wanted to know what difference the article makes in the second sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There's an important difference between the sentences.

Both are grammatically correct.

"She is the best and wisest girl in the class."  -- She tops the 
"best and wisest" girls in the class.

"She is the best and the wisest girl in the class." -- She is the best and also the wisest.

In the first, the comparison is with girls who are both "good" and "wise". In the second, the comparison is separately with "good" girls and "wise" girls.